# Will BIOS boot mode Ubuntu install be able to boot when firmware "Fast Boot" is "Ultra Fast"?

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I have an AsRock mainboard with UEFI BIOS P1.50 02/14/2014. The firmware "Fast Boot" option is set to "Fast", Boot Option #1 is set to "AHCI P4: OCZ-VERT...": this is BIOS not UEFI boot. This boot disk has an MBR partitioning scheme (`# parted -l | grep Partition\ Table:`). Therefore Ubuntu 14.04 is installed in BIOS/CMS (Grub-PC) mode. The Ubuntu boot process ends in a text console (no GUI). There is no external graphics card in use. The stock Ubuntu kernel is replaced with Ubuntu supplied mainline 3.16.0-031600rc6-generic.

`dmesg` outputs lines containing BIOS, like:

- `SMBIOS 2.7 present`
- `Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area`
- `Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!`
- `[Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored`
- `BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found`

The ASRock BIOS it selves display this help text for "Ultra Fast - Fast Boot":

> Ultra Fast mode is only supported by Windows 8 and the VBIOS must
>   support UEFI GOP if you are using an external graphics card. Please
>   notice that Ultra Fast mode will boot so fast that the only way to
>   enter this UEFI Setup Utility is to Clear CMOS or run the Restart to
>   UEFI utility in Windows.

Assumptions:

1. I suspect after changing UEFI setting "Fast Boot" to "Ultra Fast" that the machine will no longer boot into Ubuntu's console.
2. I expect when first exchanging "Grub-pc" with "Grub-efi", that the machine will still be able to boot to a grub menu (*thus allowing to change the "Fast Boot" setting back to "Fast" without clearing CMOS*).

Are these two "Fast Boot" assumptions correct, and/or, may I expect Ubuntu 14.04 running mainline kernel 3.16rc6 and Grub-efi to still boot to console after enabling **UEFI Ultra Fast Boot**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ultra Fast no longer boots BIOS mode Ubuntu

When changing "Fast Boot" from "Fast" to "Ultra Fast" (BIOS+MBR) indeed Ubuntu does no longer boot in its text console.

### Boot enters the ASRock UEFI Setup Utility instead

That is a luck. Now there is no need to clear the CMOS to enter the Setup utility again, just change the "Fast Boot" value and reboot.

## Ultra Fast requires EFI/UEFI mode Ubuntu

After [converting the existing Ubuntu installation from CMS/BIOS boot into EFI/UEFI boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair) the same machine is able to boot Ubuntu using Ultra Fast boot mode. Access to UEFI setup utility is no longer possible using <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> key combinations during boot.

Comment: It's worth noting that the UEFI setup utility should be accessible from the grub menu.