# Lubuntu refuses to boot from HDD despite numerous tries with boot-repair

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I remember problems setting up my Lubuntu with UEFI/Legacy boot mode. That was more than a year ago and the system worked fine - until now. For whatever reason, it refuses to boot again.

I went through a number of different recipes involving boot-repair, but it still won't boot. The paste from boot-repair can be found here http://paste.ubuntu.com/10861892/.

My approach was to format my EFI partition again in FAT32 and assign the boot flag to it before running boot-repair. In boot-repair > advanced options > GRUB location, I cannot select my EFI partition (sda1) in the field 'separate /boot partition'. However, it does not complain about not finding the EFI partition. The EFI partition (sda1) also shows up in the /etc/fstab (sda4), after running boot-repair:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=85ae8106-d4ae-49ee-9e77-e93aa86c6e63 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=D954-89D5  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ffc890d1-0cd6-4a5b-86c3-b6c8db17a1e1 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=507de4f4-fde7-4c5b-badd-66defcbc27f5 none            swap    sw              0       0
#UUID=d2bb4e60-b497-4cd4-8b8c-04ffe5f3085a  /boot   ext4    defaults    0   2
```

In my BIOS, however, I do not find any boot loader that uses UEFI.

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Thanks,
Michael

**EDIT**

I went foward and installed [rEFInd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/), which boots, but doesn't find Lubuntu either...

**SOLUTION**

I discovered this post https://askubuntu.com/a/509564/395808, which describes how to do the BIOS/UEFI conversion. Apparently, this works for me.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! It appears there is some corruption here based on your pastebin. Is this a dual boot system?

Comment: Thanks! No, it's not a dual boot system - at least it's not supposed to be one...