# Ubuntu XPS13 Sputnik boot order and Bios configuration?

Tags: 14.04, dell, sputnik

I had a superblock issue on my Dell XPS13 Sputnik edition. Trying to get Ubuntu back booting.

Does anyone know which partition it should boot from? 
Bios is set to Legacy should this be so?

Originally Ubuntu 12.04, update to 14.04. I used Clonezilla to clone the disk and it ran some ordering flags on the partitions, and set boot to Sda1 the Dell Utility partition @ 300mb after fixing the issue.

Other partitions are:
Sda2 OS @ 493mb,
Sda3 ext4 220mb,
Sda4 extends Sda5 Linux-swap.

Anyone have any ideas, how I can get back up and running?

Comment: You should just do boot repair. Possible duplicate of [Which commands to convert a Ubuntu BIOS install to EFI/UEFI without boot-repair on single boot hardware?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In retrospect it was potentially three difficult questions to answer – whilst in the panic stage of system down.  I will try my best to answer them should anyone from the future stumble across this.

These are the steps I followed…

- Download and install [Parted Magic](https://partedmagic.com/) with [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) as it has a lot of good tools in one place.
- Ran the USB disk with Parted Magic on, by changing the boot order in BIOS.
- Ran TestDisk to scan the partitions and report errors.
- Ran Clonezilla to back-up partitions to an external drive and then repair the Superblock issues.
- Changed boot disk with GParted to Sda3 the main partition (listed above).
- Used Lilo to detected and repair the boot loader (Grub2).
- This got me to a Ubuntu boot window. However despite going through the long list of Ubuntu images, with their different kernal versions, I ended  in Kernal Panic on each and everyone of them. I do vaguely, remember one of these worked the previous time I got in this mess.

I then wiped all the disk with partitions, and installed Ubuntu 16.04. I can confirm that Dell XPS 13 Project Sputnik 1st Edition works very well on the new OS and would recommend to all would be early adopters.

All the saved files from the external drive have been copied after setting their permission to chmod 777.

Over & out!