# conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver

Tags: uefi

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64 with Core i3-2100 and GA-H61M-DS2,I removed HIS 6670 iSilence 5 1GB recently because it crashed randomly on Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64 and removed fglrx by this [How do I remove the proprietary ATI drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers) ,now everything work well except this [Which commands to convert a Ubuntu BIOS install to EFI/UEFI without boot-repair on single boot hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair) show me

```
$ dmesg | grep EFI
efi: EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends
fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
```

but I got

```
$ dmesg | grep EFI
efi: EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends
fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
```

Boot Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64 Live USB has the same problem

Comment: Are both these accounts https://askubuntu.com/users/607525/cuthead, https://askubuntu.com/users/694237/cuthead yours? Please [ask for merging them](https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts), then you will be able to edit your own posts without [approval](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/721893).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cuthead@jinsha:~$ dmesg |grep EFI
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.31 by American Megatrends
[    0.726930] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    1.111718] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    1.369398] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
```

I update to 17.04 and I got intel alternative driver,problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to post here because the solution was hard to find on the net
In Debian Jessie last update 8.9 (Sept 2017):
https://gist.github.com/Rambou/c6769caee19b0b9915d8342b86c3ef72

From the web site I just did the last part of #5

I had a problem with the nouveaufb driver.
Nouveau was the new comer installed by my migration towards UEFI and it was called on boot time making the boot console to stop 
The most enoying problem was that I was not able to log in any terminal using CTL ALT F1 or F2 ... F6., but ALT F7 was bringing me back to the gui.
SO .. 
 I did create a file in /etc/modprobe.d called blacklist-nouveau.conf .
The file name can be anything.conf as it is not relevant except for us "Humans"

So replace your conflicting driver name in accordance in the file.

```
# Blacklist-nouveau.conf list

blacklist nouveau

blacklist lbm-nouveau

options nouveau modeset=0

alias nouveau off

alias lbm-nouveau off

#END
```

The next command will create a new file called nouveau-kms.conf and push  a string into it.

```
sudo echo options nouveau modeset=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf
```

After this you have to run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot

This solve this issue